# SOLR: query multiple value on multiple fields

Tags: python, solr

I have recently started using Solr. I have a json file of this type that I have indexed.

```
[
    {
        "id": 1, 
        "ent":  "Playa_Limbo", 
        "title": "System of a Down briefly disbanded in limbo.", 
        "text": "Playa isn't the first word of vocabolary of..."
        },
    {
        "id": 2, 
        "ent":  "Playa_Limbo", 
        "title": "System of a Down play a game called limbo.", 
        "text": "Limbo is a fantastic game..."
        },
    {
        "id": 3, 
        "ent":  "System_of_a_Down_-LRB-album-RRB-", 
        "title": "System of a Down briefly disbanded in limbo.", 
        "text": "System of a Down is the debut studio album ... "
        },
    {
        "id": 4, 
        "ent":  "Limbo_-LRB-disambiguation-RRB-", 
    [...]
]
```

For each title in the dataset, I would like to find the text that is more relevant to the title.
For example, for "System of a Down briefly disbanded in limbo" I would like it to return the text of the element with id = 3. In fact it is more inherent than the one with id = 1.

So I wrote this python script which does what I want.

```
list_title = ["System of a Down[...]", "title_2", "title_3", ...]
for title in list_title:
    title = title.replace(" ", "%20")

    ###text: System of a Down[...] title: "System of a Down[...]"
    q = "text:%20" + title + "%20" + "title:%20" + '"' + title + '"' 

    connection = urlopen('http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?defType=dismax&fl=context,%20score&q='+q+'&qf=context%20claim&rows=1')
    response = json.load(connection)

    # Print the text of each document.
    for document in response['response']['docs']:
        print(document["text"][0])
```

However it is extremely slow and inefficient.
Is there a way for example to make a single call?
Or a different way of writing the query or something faster?

Thank you in advance

Comment: How slow is the query? How many titles are you looking up? Where does the `list_title` list get populated from? Is `title` in the document related to `list_title` in your program?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The script is able to perform approximately 400 requests per minute. list_title is populated from a file with 35,000 titles, so I'm looking for 35,000 titles. So it would take about 87 minutes. Yes, title in the document is related to list_title.

Comment: You can probably easily parallize that script to make several requests in parallel. Your core should be able to handle hundreds of requests/s on normal hardware and with a decently sized index. You could also probably write a streaming expression that does it for you; see https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_7/stream-source-reference.html#search -- depending on how often you need to do this, 87 minutes might be perfectly sensible.